# Problema JButton JavaSwing

Tags: java, java-swing

tenia una duda con respecto a la componente JButton. Para implementar lo que necesito, hago uso de un numero variable de botones (Todos son iguales en cuanto a caracteristicas (Nombre del boton, funcion etc)) y como todo eso es igual, he pensado en implementarlo como un array de botones que se crearan automaticamente y se situaran tambien automaticamente en la pantalla. El problema esta en que el numero de botones que tengo que generar es variable (Unas veces necesitare 4 botones otras 8 etc) He probado a implementarlo de esta manera pero claro tengo el problema del action listener y no se como solucionarlo

```
public class PruebaBotones extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JButton[] aBotones = new JButton[3]; //Array de botones
private JLabel mensaje;
private int posY = 20;

public PruebaBotones()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        aBotones[i] = new JButton("Boton "+(i+1));
        aBotones[i].setSize(300 , 30);
        aBotones[i].addActionListener(this);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        aBotones[i].setLocation(20 , posY);
        add(aBotones[i]);
        aBotones[i].setVisible(true);

        posY = posY + 50; //Variamos la posicion Y para que se situe uno debajo del otro

    }
```

Una vez tengo creado los botones y su funcionamiento me he dispuesto a realizar el ActionListener, como es un ejemplo, lo unico que hago es modificar una etiqueta para comprobar que el evento se efectua correctamente

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if(actionEvent.getSource() == aBotones[0]) //Pulsamos el 1 boton
    {
        mensaje.setText("Boton pulsado 1");

    } //Lo mismo para los demas casos
    if(actionEvent.getSource() == aBotones[1]) //Pulsamos el 2 boton
    {
        mensaje.setText("Boton pulsado 2");
    }
    if(actionEvent.getSource() == aBotones[2]) //Pulsamos el 3 boton
    {
        mensaje.setText("Boton pulsado 3");
    }

}
```

Hasta ahi todo correcto y funciona, el problema viene cuando necesito mas elementos de los que he definido en el ActionListener porque el array de botones lo he definido como un numero fijo (En mi caso 3) pero claro a lo mejor necesito 5 o 9 o 1 o los que sea y si pasa eso no tengo forma de cambiar el ActionListener.

Alguna idea de como implementar esto de la misma forma a como lo tengo yo o parecido para que realice la misma funcion??

Habia pensado en algo asi pero me da error.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        aBotones[i] = new JButton("Boton "+(i+1));
        aBotones[i].setSize(300 , 30);
        aBotones[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                mensaje.setText("Boton pulsado "+i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Muchas Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Que error? Saludos.

Comment: Pienso que el error debe ser porque la variable local a la que se hace referencia debe ser `final`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pienso que la solución es sencilla, y es haciendo un bucle for dentro del `actionPerformed`.

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        for (int i = 0; i < aBotones.length; i++) 
            if(e.getSource() == aBotones[i]) //Pulsamos el boton correspond.
                mensaje.setText("Boton pulsado " + (i+1));
    }
```

P.d. He hecho la prueba y me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Si necesitas alguna aclaración, me lo dices.